# How can i customize an XML from data table?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

How can i customize an XML from data table?
Or can i directly get the customized xml from sql server?

Edited: I am getting some row in my data table, which i need to customized in the following format.

```
<XML>
<OfficeHours><monday>1:30-4:30, 5:30-7:00</monday><tuesday>3-7</tuesday></OfficeHours> <OfficePhone>407-421-8495</OfficePhone> <OfficeAddress>610 Sycamore St, Celebration FL 34747</OfficeAddress> <AffiliateID>451234</AffiliateID> <OfficeWebsite>http://www.XYZ.com</OfficeWebsite> </xml>
```

Which later will be read by some PHP site, using some API, but confuse with also that should i save the generated XML at the server of i should display it in web page, which 
the PHP site will read.

Edited: something like this is the datatable row. One row only, i am just copying hte feilds.

```
id  CompanyName DoctorName1 DoctorName2 DoctorName3 AddressLine1    AddressLine2    AddressLine3    AddressCity AddressProvince AddressCountry  AddressPostal   CompanyPhone    CompanyFax  Website PrimaryContact  PrimaryEmail    ShortDescription    LongDescription HoursSunday HoursMonday HoursTuesday    HoursWednesday  HoursThursday   HoursFriday HoursSaturday   ProgEssBodyToxin    ProgEssNerve    ProgEssWellness ProgEssOxygen   ProgEssMax  ProgMLHealthCenter  ProgWellness    AffiliateID PaymentVisa PaymentMasterCard   PaymentAMEX PaymentCheck    Latitude    Longitude
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a [datatype XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx) in sql server 2008 which gives you proper customized xml string. However, if you provide some sample on what customization you mean, then some reasonable answers can be given.

Comment: see, i get a row of a table in the DB on the basis of some id, that row is filled in Datatable but i want theses fields to be customized.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - Can you add sample data as stored in your table and the expected customized data as you need in your question?